# minified error 482 after upload nextjs app

Tags: next.js

I uploaded my nextJs app on GitHub pages, The first page works correctly but when use  to switch pages, an error occurs
***https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=482***

but I can change the page manually in the URL,
and react doesn't show a minified error description
You can see my website in GitHub pages with the below link
https://mehrad94.github.io/portfolio/services